# Lookup items says "Count Related"

Tags: lookup-column

I am not very skilled with SharePoint, but I have been tasked with using it on a daily basis, and am always at least "trying" to make improvements to it.  The issue I am having today is that I have 2 separate lists for clients.  1 is called clients (that has their information), another is a list of other information relating to that company.  For the second list, I have a look-up that links it to the clients list, but I want to be able to put a clickable link in the 1st list that goes to the second.  I thought the best way to do that would be through a look-up column, but when I try to choose one of the values, it says "count related", but obviously I don't want count, I want it to link to the page.  Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew,

You can do that by using Connected Web Parts most easily.. Once you have the lookups in place you can actually drop both the List View Web Parts in a single place and create a connection between them so that the "Other List" web part filters itself on selection of "Clients" List Web Part..

How-To:

[Connecting web parts with a selector and a detail pane](http://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/05/21/connecting-web-parts-with-a-selector-and-a-detail-pane-sharepoint-2010-version/)